# Updating RibbonMenu items while menu is open?

Tags: excel, vsto, ribbon

Is it possible to update all RibbonControls in a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonMenu` while it's already open?

I have tried, but I can't get it to work. Even if I set the `RibbonMenu` to `Dynamic=true`, the items only seem to refresh when I close and re-open the `RibbonMenu`.

Example (I used the ribbon-designer in Visual Studio 2010):

- Let's say I have added a `RibbonGroup`
- Then I have added a `RibbonMenu` and set the property `Dynamic=true`
- Then I have added two `RibbonButton`controls to the RibbonMenu with the `Label` "A" and "B".

Now I can start excel, go to my ribbon tab and can open my ribbon menu to see my two buttons `Label` "A" and "B".

I can also change these button texts at runtime programmatically and see the changed texts, when I open the `RibbonMenu`.

---

**BUT, now my question:**
Can I change these button texts at runtime WHILE the `RibbonMenu` is already open?? I can't get this to work!

---

P.S. I also tried to close and reopen the `RibbonMenu` by a timer and then invalidate it. But although the `RibbonButton.Label` property has been changed in the debugger, the GUI does not update immediately.

Comment: Please provide more detail: What do you mean by "update" the controls? What's supposed to happen? Please provide any related code...

Comment: No, that's not possible because there's nothing to trigger it. In the Ribbon XML that underlies what the Designer offers, either Ribbon.InvalidateControl or Ribbon.Invalidate needs to be executed. But while the menu is displayed there's no way to execute such code.